# Core data do not fetch record

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

i added website field in core data after adding other attributes to xcdatamodel, and i am saving this attribute like this

```
- (void)fetchandSaveGWTGsSince:(NSString *)since
{

    NSString *completeURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@api.php?action=get_all_gwtgs&sinceDate=%@", BASE_URL, since];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:completeURL];
//    self.loggingEnable = NO;
    if (self.loggingEnable == YES)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", [since integerValue]-18000]);
        NSLog(@"%@", since);
        NSLog(@"%@", [[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:(NSTimeInterval)[since integerValue]] description]);
        NSLog(@"%@", [[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:((NSTimeInterval)[since integerValue])-18000] description]);
        NSLog(@"%@", completeURL);
    }

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    request.timeoutInterval = REQUEST_TIMEOUT;

    [AFJSONRequestOperation addAcceptableContentTypes:[NSSet setWithObject:@"text/html"]];
    AFJSONRequestOperation *operation =
    [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON)
     {
         NSDictionary *resDict  = (NSDictionary *)JSON;
         if (self.loggingEnable == YES)
         {
             NSLog(@"Response GWTGs : %@", resDict);
         }
         if ([[resDict objectForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"success"])
         {
             NSArray *data = [[resDict objectForKey:@"data"] objectAtIndex:0];
             NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[Common apd] managedObjectContext];
             if ([data count] > 0)
             {
                 [data enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
                 {

                     NSDictionary *gwtgDict = (NSDictionary *)obj;
                     if ([gwtgDict objectForKey:@"gwtg_id"])
                     {
                         NSArray *locationInfos = [self getGWTGsWithGWTG_ID:[gwtgDict objectForKey:@"gwtg_id"]];
                         if ([locationInfos count] > 0)
                         {
                             for (Location *location in locationInfos)
                             {
                                 [context deleteObject:location];
                                 NSError *error = nil;
                                 if (![context save:&error]) {
                                     // Handle the error.
                                     if (self.loggingEnable == YES)
                                     {
                                         NSLog(@"error deleting gwtg : %@", [location description]);
                                     }
                                 }
                             }
                         }
                     }
                 }];

             }
             [data enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
              {
                  NSDictionary *gwtgInfo = (NSDictionary *)obj;
                  /*
                   gwtg_status = 0 => Inactive Record
                   gwtg_status = 1 => New Record/Active Record
                   gwtg_status = 2 => Updated Record
                   gwtg_status = 3 => Deleted Record
                   */
                  if ([[gwtgInfo objectForKey:@"gwtg_status"] intValue] != 3)
                  {
                      GWTG *gwtg = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"GWTG" inManagedObjectContext:context];
                      gwtg.gwtg_id = ([[gwtgInfo objectForKey:@"gwtg_id"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) ? @"" : [gwtgInfo objectForKey:@"gwtg_id"];

                      NSData *celData = [NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString:[gwtgInfo objectForKey:@"celebrity_name"]];
                      NSString *celName = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:celData encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy];
                      gwtg.celebrity_name = ([celName isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) ? @"" : celName;

                      gwtg.location_id = ([[gwtgInfo objectForKey:@"location_id"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) ? @"" : [gwtgInfo objectForKey:@"location_id"];

                      NSData *loc_cityData = [NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString:[gwtgInfo objectForKey:@"location_city"]];
                      NSString *loc_cityName = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:loc_cityData encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy];
                      gwtg.location_city = ([loc_cityName isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) ? @"" : loc_cityName;

                      NSData *cityData = [NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString:[gwtgInfo objectForKey:@"city"]];
                      NSString *cityName = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:cityData encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy];
                      gwtg.city = ([cityName isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) ? @"" : cityName;

                      NSData *stateData = [NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString:[gwtgInfo objectForKey:@"state"]];
                      NSString *stateName = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:stateData encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy];
                      gwtg.state = ([stateName isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) ? @"" : stateName;

                      NSData *countryData = [NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString:[gwtgInfo objectForKey:@"country"]];
                      NSString *countryName = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:countryData encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy];
                      gwtg.country = ([countryName isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) ? @"" : countryName;

                      gwtg.a_consuming = ([[gwtgInfo objectForKey:@"a_consuming"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) ? @"" : [gwtgInfo objectForKey:@"a_consuming"];
                      gwtg.a_playing = ([[gwtgInfo objectForKey:@"a_playing"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) ? @"" : [gwtgInfo objectForKey:@"a_playing"];
                      gwtg.a_lodging = ([[gwtgInfo objectForKey:@"a_lodging"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) ? @"" : [gwtgInfo objectForKey:@"a_lodging"];
                      gwtg.a_shopping = ([[gwtgInfo objectForKey:@"a_shopping"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) ? @"" : [gwtgInfo objectForKey:@"a_shopping"];
                      gwtg.a_recommending = ([[gwtgInfo objectForKey:@"a_recommending"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) ? @"" : [gwtgInfo objectForKey:@"a_recommending"];
                      gwtg.w_g_here = ([[gwtgInfo objectForKey:@"w_g_here"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) ? @"" : [gwtgInfo objectForKey:@"w_g_here"];

                      NSData *locData = [NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString:[gwtgInfo objectForKey:@"location_name"]];
                      NSString *locName = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:locData encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy];
                      gwtg.location_name = ([locName isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) ? @"" : locName;

                      //location_address, we_go_here, credit

                      NSData *locAdData = [NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString:[gwtgInfo objectForKey:@"location_address"]];
                      NSString *locAdName = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:locAdData encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy];
                      gwtg.location_address = ([locAdName isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) ? @"" : locAdName;

                      gwtg.location_phone = ([[gwtgInfo objectForKey:@"location_phone"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) ? @"" : [gwtgInfo objectForKey:@"location_phone"];

                      gwtg.location_zip_code = ([[gwtgInfo objectForKey:@"location_zip_code"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) ? @"" : [gwtgInfo objectForKey:@"location_zip_code"];

                      NSData *wghData = [NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString:[gwtgInfo objectForKey:@"we_go_here"]];
                      NSString *wghName = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:wghData encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy];
                      gwtg.we_go_here = ([wghName isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) ? @"" : wghName;

                      gwtg.wgh_date = ([[gwtgInfo objectForKey:@"wgh_date"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) ? @"" : [gwtgInfo objectForKey:@"wgh_date"];

                      NSData *creData = [NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString:[gwtgInfo objectForKey:@"credit"]];
                      NSString *creName = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:creData encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy];
                      gwtg.credit = ([creName isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) ? @"" : creName;

                      NSData *webSite_Data = [NSData dataWithBase64EncodedString:[gwtgInfo objectForKey:@"website"]];
                      NSString *add_website = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:webSite_Data encoding:NSStringEncodingConversionAllowLossy];
                      gwtg.website = ([add_website isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) ? @"" : add_website;



                      gwtg.gwtg_status = ([[gwtgInfo objectForKey:@"gwtg_status"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) ? @"" : [gwtgInfo objectForKey:@"gwtg_status"];

                      gwtg.gwtg_isactive = ([[gwtgInfo objectForKey:@"gwtg_isactive"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) ? @"" : [gwtgInfo objectForKey:@"gwtg_isactive"];

                      gwtg.addeddate = ([[gwtgInfo objectForKey:@"addeddate"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) ? @"" : [gwtgInfo objectForKey:@"addeddate"];
                      gwtg.modifieddate = ([[gwtgInfo objectForKey:@"modifieddate"] isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) ? @"" : [gwtgInfo objectForKey:@"modifieddate"];

                      if (self.loggingEnable == YES)
                      {
                          NSLog(@"----Location----");
                          NSLog(@"%@", gwtg.gwtg_id);
                          NSLog(@"%@", gwtg.celebrity_name);
                          NSLog(@"%@", gwtg.location_id);
                          NSLog(@"%@", gwtg.city);
                          NSLog(@"%@", gwtg.state);
                          NSLog(@"%@", gwtg.country);
                          NSLog(@"%@", gwtg.a_consuming);
                          NSLog(@"%@", gwtg.a_playing);
                          NSLog(@"%@", gwtg.a_lodging);
                          NSLog(@"%@", gwtg.a_shopping);
                          NSLog(@"%@", gwtg.a_recommending);
                          NSLog(@"%@", gwtg.w_g_here);
                          NSLog(@"%@", gwtg.location_name);
                          NSLog(@"%@", gwtg.location_address);
                          NSLog(@"%@", gwtg.location_phone);
                          NSLog(@"%@", gwtg.location_zip_code);
                          NSLog(@"%@", gwtg.we_go_here);
                          NSLog(@"%@", gwtg.wgh_date);
                          NSLog(@"%@", gwtg.credit);
                          NSLog(@"%@", gwtg.website);
                          NSLog(@"%@", gwtg.gwtg_status);
                          NSLog(@"%@", gwtg.addeddate);
                          NSLog(@"%@", gwtg.modifieddate);
                          NSLog(@"%@", gwtg.gwtg_isactive);
                      }

                      NSError *error;
                      if (![context save:&error]) {
                          NSLog(@"Whoops, couldn't save: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                      }
                  }
              }];

             if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:LAST_TIME_GWTG_UPDATED])
             {
                 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:LAST_TIME_GWTG_UPDATED];
             }
             NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
             NSLog(@"date last time : %@", [data description]);
             [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.f", [date timeIntervalSince1970]] forKey:LAST_TIME_GWTG_UPDATED];
             [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];

             [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kNotificationRequestFinished object:nil userInfo:nil];
         }
         else
         {
//             [Common showAlertWithTitle:@"Warning" message:[resDict objectForKey:@"message"]];
             if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:LAST_TIME_GWTG_UPDATED])
             {

             }
             else
             {
                 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"0"] forKey:LAST_TIME_GWTG_UPDATED];
                 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
             }
         }
     }
    failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON)
     {
         if (self.loggingEnable == YES)
         {
             NSLog(@"error %@", [error description]);
         }
         [Common showAlertWithTitle:@"Error Retrieving" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[error localizedDescription]]];
         if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:LAST_TIME_GWTG_UPDATED])
         {

         }
         else
         {
             [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"0"] forKey:LAST_TIME_GWTG_UPDATED];
             [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
         }
     }];
    [operation start];
}
```

and i am getting website url like this,  but it always come empty,

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _gwtgDO.website];

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

why it is always empty although i am getting website link from server correctly? is this due to reason that i added attribute later? what should i do now?

Comment: whenever you change the xcdatamodel file, you've to regenerate its classes to make it work. btw where's core data code where you are saving.?

Comment: i am saving in my coreDataManager class, i also have replaced, deleted app from simuator..i edited my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing `NSStringEncodingConversionOptions` instead of `NSStringEncoding`. I suppose you want `NSString *add_website = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:webSite_Data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];` for UTF-8 encoding, for example.

More about the encodings here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html

Comment: What I'm saying is there should be `NSStringEncoding` enum going into `[NSString initWithData:encoding:]`, but you are passing it `NSStringEncodingConversionOptions`. I don't think that is desired behavior.

Comment: No idea, if you put `NSLog(@"Here: %@", add_website)` after the `NSString *add_website = [[NSString alloc] initWithData...`, do you see the text encoded correctly?

Comment: Ok, that is interesting, since you don't specify the encoding (so that it shouldn't know whether to encode it by UTF-8, ASCII, ...)

Comment: my problem is not for saving, i want to get that data, do u understand  my problem?

Comment: Yes, but if you are not able to retrieve that data, it might be because that data was never saved correctly. Also, Core Data would throw an exception if you were accessing an non-existing object. So you are accessing an existing, fetched object which does not have the data you want there. The first place would be to look right before the save, whether the data is ready to be saved or not. Also, subscribe for the `NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification` and there you get the changes that will be saved. (It passes you all changes to be saved in a dictionary).

Comment: Nothing happened as in even after registering for `NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification` notifications, you did not get notified? Because that should be the best way to tell whether you are saving well or not.